# Oracle 10g Database Package Response Time Slow

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

Recently, I have made another database for separate yearly package. Once I build and put the indexing which we already used in the previous database. The problem is the when I run the Package it took too much time to gather the information. But when I used the testDB which I used for the developing purpose it works perfectly.

The only difference which I found is the Cost value which is the change in Production Database and testDB.[image]

[image]

Comment: What's different between the environments?  If the SQL and execution plan are the same, that's a good start.  Are the indexes the same size?  Check `select bytes/1024/1024/1024 gb from all_segments where segment_name = 'PK_COA';`  If the indexes are the same, is the hardware I/O significantly different?

Answer (score 0):

Run your query on each database with the GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS hint.  Once that is done, run the following:

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'ALLSTATS LAST'))
```

This gives you a report on how many rows were processed at each step, and a good indication as to where to focus your tuning efforts. If you head over to https://asktom.oracle.com and search for "GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS" you'll see lots of examples on how to use it.